# How to do complex join between three database tables in DataWeave

Tags: join, mule, dataweave

How can I do complex joins in DataWeave? One way is to pass one join function result into another, or to nest mapping/reduce functions or update functions (depending if the end result should be a nested data structure vs. a flattened CSV file, etc. ). Is there any other more optimal approach?

Comment: Please provide more specific details like example inputs and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough RAM to handle the structures in memory, you can use some lookup strategy like this one

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var table1 = [{ id: 1, name: "John" }]
var table2 = [{ id: 1, surname: "Smith" }]
var table3 = [{ id: 1, age: 35 }]

var table2Index = table2 groupBy ((item, index) ->item.id)
var table3Index = table3 groupBy ((item, index) ->item.id)

fun getRow(table, id) = table[id as String][0]

---
table1 map ((item, index) -> {
    id: item.id,
    name: item.name,
    surname: getRow(table2Index, item.id).surname,
    age: getRow(table3Index, item.id).age
})
```

Using `groupBy` will order the structures once so then you access by key to optimize the lookup. This strategy can be used with any amount of tables.

Comment: Thanks Jorge. I guess the join function itself can't do this type of complex join, so we have to combine the three tables together "manually" with our own mapping functions.